# knockoutjs nested views dynamically loaded

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

is there something like knockout.refresh bindings?

I am attempting to have a main.htm, myview.htm

main.htm has a pageviewmodel with a observable currentviewmodel.

main.htm:

```
<div id="page">
   <div data-bind="html:CurrentViewModel().Render"> </div>
</div>
```

with a script block

```
  var appViewModel = function(){
       var self = this;
       self.CurrentViewModel = ko.observable({Render:function(){return '';}});
       return self;
    };
    var myViewModel = function(){
       var self = this;
       self.Render = ko.observable('');
       self.Name = ko.observable('blah');
       self.Load = function(){
          $.get('views/myview.htm', function(data) {
             var res = data;
             self.Render(res);
             self.Name('blldjkfa');
          },"html");
       };
       return self;
    };
```

var pagemodel = new appViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(pagemodel,$('#page')[0]);

myView.htm:

```
<div>
hello world <span data-bind="text:Name">a</span>
</div>
```

at some point the current view model gets set

```
var loadedModel = new mainViewModel();
pagemodel.CurrentViewModel(loadedModel);
loadedModel.Load();
```

when load gets called the html of the site is populated but the data-bind is not applied.
however if i put a span with the same a into the block it does display the data from the new view model.

...Leading me to believe that i need to refresh the binding somehow... that or set html differently?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you just call `applyBindings` with these parameters:

```
ko.applyBindings(yourModel, HTMLElement);
```

where HTMLElement is something like $('#yourElementId')[0] if you're using jQuery.  Knockout applies bindings starting with that element as the root.  You can read more about  `applyBindings` here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html under the "Activating knockout" section.  Good luck.

Comment: I tried that the problem is that the pageviewmodel is bound at the #page level and applying it to a nested div causes an error

Comment: hm, that error must be from something else, because applyBindings is smart enough not to step on its own toes.  Can you post a fiddle that's getting the error you describe?  Have you tried calling just simply applyBindings(pageviewmodel, $('#page')[0]) again?